# How to retrieve all texts that a word appear

Tags: r, list, split

I have a data frame consisting of words that appear in different texts.

```
     word text
1     a    1
2     a    2
3     a    5
4     b    1
5     b    3
6     c    1
7     c    3
8     c    4
9     d    4
10    e    2
11    e    4
12    f    3
13    g    2
14    h    5
15    i    5
```

I want to have an output for each word like this:

```
a
[1] 1 2 5
b
[1] 1 3 
...
```

And is there any way that all the texts of each word can be retrieved at the same time without having to type "a" or "b" each time I want to find the texts of a particular word?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can just `split` your `text` by `word`.

```r
split(df$text, df$word)

$a
[1] 1 2 5

$b
[1] 1 3

$c
[1] 1 3 4

$d
[1] 4

$e
[1] 2 4

$f
[1] 3

$g
[1] 2

$h
[1] 5

$i
[1] 5
```

Comment: Many thanks @user2974951 and @benson23!! They do work for me now!!

Answer (score 4):

Another base R option is `unstack`:

```
unstack(df, text~word)
$a
[1] 1 2 5

$b
[1] 1 3

$c
[1] 1 3 4
```

---

```
unstack(rev(df))
$a
[1] 1 2 5

$b
[1] 1 3

$c
[1] 1 3 4
```

Comment: Many thanks @Onyambu!!

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in `dat`

```
> tapply(dat$text,dat$word,FUN=as.vector)
$a
[1] 1 2 5

$b
[1] 1 3

$c
[1] 1 3 4

$d
[1] 4

$e
[1] 2 4

$f
[1] 3

$g
[1] 2

$h
[1] 5

$i
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution using purrr `map`:

```
map(unique(df$word),\(x){ 
        df %>% filter(word==x) %>% pull(text)
  }) %>% 
  purrr::set_names(unique(df$word)) 

> $a 
> [1] 1 2 5
> 
> $b 
> [1] 1 3
> 
> $c 
> [1] 1 3 4
> ...
```

Comment: Many thanks @pluke!!

Answer (score 1):

**tidyverse**

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              word = c("a","a","a","b","b","c",
                       "c","c","d","e","e","f","g","h","i"),
              text = c(1L,2L,5L,1L,3L,1L,3L,4L,
                       4L,2L,4L,3L,2L,5L,5L)
)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  nest_by(word) %>% 
  deframe() %>% 
  map(pull)
#> $a
#> [1] 1 2 5
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 1 3
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 1 3 4
#> 
#> $d
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> $e
#> [1] 2 4
#> 
#> $f
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $g
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $h
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $i
#> [1] 5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks @Yuriy Saraykin!!

Comment: so much nicer than my version, I forgot about `nest`