# How to calculate mean value from a data frame with values not in the same vector

Tags: r

I got a data frame like this:

```
     word               value
1     a                  3
2     b                  c(1, 10, 15, 17)
3     c                  8
4     d                  c(2,9)
5     e                  c(3, 7, 8, 12, 16, 17, 19)
6     f                  6
```

...
I want the value column to be numeric so that I can calculate the mean value for words such as b, d, e, and so on.
Many thanks!

Comment: This is basically the same as your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77571002/how-to-retrieve-all-texts-that-a-word-appear.

Comment: Yes because I enframe it back to data frame and it concatenate values so I cannot calculate the mean values then :(.

Comment: Why are you doing that? Having the result in a list is much better and allows you to average these without having to convert it back to numbers?

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- tibble::tribble(~"word",~"value",
                      "a", "3",
                      "b", "c(1, 10, 15, 17)",
                      "c", "8",
                      "d", "c(2,9)",
                      "e", "c(3, 7, 8, 12, 16, 17, 19)",
                      "f", "6")

ls <- list(df, df)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(ls,
~.x |> 
  tidyr::separate_rows(value, sep = ",") |> 
  mutate(value = readr::parse_number(value)) |> 
  group_by(word) |> 
  summarise(mean = mean(value))
)
```

Comment: Many thanks @Julian!!

Comment: May I ask if this can work with for loop? I am applying for many csv files in a directory and adding this code and write csv as an output for each file but no mean values were calculated. All files in the new directory are still the same. Many thanks!

Comment: Of course, see my edit-

Comment: Many thanks for your help!! @Julian

Answer (score 1):

you can try the code below with `str2lang` + `eval`

```
transform(
    df,
    meanval = sapply(
        eval(str2lang(sprintf("list(%s)", toString(value)))),
        mean
    )
)
```

which gives

```
  word                      value  meanval
1    a                          3  3.00000
2    b           c(1, 10, 15, 17) 10.75000
3    c                          8  8.00000
4    d                     c(2,9)  5.50000
5    e c(3, 7, 8, 12, 16, 17, 19) 11.71429
6    f                          6  6.00000
```

## data

```
df <- structure(list(word = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), value = c("3", 
"c(1, 10, 15, 17)", "8", "c(2,9)", "c(3, 7, 8, 12, 16, 17, 19)",
"6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4",
"5", "6"))
```

Comment: Many thanks @ThomasIsCoding!!